# Java 6 - how to make JWindow transparent?

Tags: java, swing, transparency, java-6, translucency

I am just wondering...  I saw many examples but they all dedicated for Java 7 only :( So my question is:

Is there a more or less optimal way to make transparent `JWindow` (or undecorated `JFrame`) with Java 6?

Comment: The transparent ability was introduced as of [1.6.0_10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#6u10).  If the users are using that version or lower, they are using an insecure JRE and should update it.

Comment: @Diego C Nascimento I want transparent see question title ; I don't get it can it be made transparent by its paint method overriding? I couldn't find any related example... Can you advise some optimal way for JDK 1.6?

Comment: Check out [window translucency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: I think you should not base your code on java 6, better to use only java 7

Comment: @Tom I'd love to but the question is about having transparent JWindow with Java 6; I am interested in some at least code snippets in this area but as for now I couldn't find any my bad :S If you can share some that would be great ;)

Comment: @user592704 I don't have any examples of my own as the days of Swing programming are long gone for me. The tutorial I linked to should provide you with a starting point. It covers the use of the `setOpacity(float)` method of the `Window` class. `JWindow` is a subclass of this very class so you should be just fine.

Comment: yes there no issue, note in Java6 aren't unreasonably limits in compare with Java7

Comment: @user592704  You seem to be ignoring both me and common sense.  1.6.0_10!!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I know what you saying and I do agree with you. I am going to use 1.6.0_10+ of course; The only annoying thing I can't use Java 7 that what really the question is about. All my googling gives tuts etc for java 7 :S Anyway thank you for correct jdk version recall it is a really helpful starting point I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a `JWindow` translucent is very simple. Window translucency has been available for as long as I can remember, even in a library as archaic as AWT.

The Swing `JWindow` is a subclass of the `java.awt.Window` class, which defines a method called `setOpacity`. All you need to do is pass a `float` value between 0 and 1.

Here's the most basic example imaginable:

```
JWindow window = new JWindow();
window.setSize(300,200);
window.setOpacity(0.5f); //this will make the window half-transparent
```

For a fully transparent window, call `window.setOpacity(0.0f)`

There are many more things you can do with the built in functionality. Read up on the subject [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: *"Window translucency has been available for as long as I can remember,.."* You must be young, because it was introduced in 1.6.0_10, as I stated in my first comment which pointed to the **same page** that you later linked.

Comment: @AndrewThompson that is true, I am young

Comment: @Andrew Thompson it is fine. I know that, too, it is available in Java 6 but the current googling gives Java 7 snippets in this area only. The point is I do remember a year or so ago I really could see some tutorials for jdk 1.6 describing how to make transparent jwindow or so; but as for now I have no "jwindow transparent" snippets for jdk 1.6 which I store locally so I really hope someone maybe has ones :)  Tom digged out some related snippets which I am going to try a little bit later and I do appreciate his help  :)

Comment: @Tom thanks I'll try the code a little bit later and report my result